# How to put buttons in listview items, which can change data in that particular list item, which corresponds to a row of the SQLIte database ?

Tags: android, sqlite, listview

I have an activity which displays a listview containing the name, quantity and price of a product in each of the listview items. Each list item has a sale button, which when pressed should reduce the quantity of that particular product who's sale button was pressed.

I am having trouble in finding out which list item's (i.e product's) sale button is pressed.... I am not able to get the Id of the list item who's sale button is pressed.

I have set the setOnClickListener on the Sale button in the bindView method in the class that extends from the CursorAdapter class like this.

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    // TODO: Fill out this method
    TextView itemName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name);
    TextView itemSummary = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.summary);
    TextView itemPrice = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.price);
    Button saleButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.sale_button);
    final Context context1 = context;
    final View view1 = view;
    final Cursor cursor1 = cursor;
    saleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            handleClick(context1, cursor1,view1);
        }
    });
 // Extract properties from cursor
    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ItemEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_NAME));
    String summary = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ItemEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_QUANTITY));
    String price = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ItemEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_SELLING_PRICE));
    // If the pet breed is empty string or null, then use some default text
    // that says "Unknown breed", so the TextView isn't blank.
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(summary)) {
        summary = context.getString(R.string.unknown_quantity);
    }
    // Populate fields with extracted properties
    itemName.setText(name);
    itemSummary.setText("In Stock: " + summary);
    itemPrice.setText("$ " + price);
}
```

Here is the handleClick method in the same class.

```
 public void handleClick(Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    // access your DB here, {item} is available if you need the data

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    String quantity = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ItemEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_QUANTITY));
    int editedQuantity = Integer.parseInt(quantity);
    if (editedQuantity == 0) {
        return;
    }
    else {
        values.put(ItemEntry.COLUMN_ITEM_QUANTITY, editedQuantity - 1);
        context.getContentResolver().update(Uri.parse(ItemEntry.CONTENT_URI + "/" + String.valueOf(cursor.getPosition()+1)), values, null, null);
    }
}
```

The problem i am facing is that when any Sale button present on any list item is pressed, the quantity on the last list item is reduced instead of the quantity in respective list item who's Sale button is clicked.

Comment: You need to store Cursor position... Every bindView call is called with same Cursor but it points to different row..

Comment: @Selvin,is that done by `int position  = cursor.getPosition()`  ?

Comment: Yes... But then you have to use it : pass to handleClick and there moveToPosition

Comment: Thanks !! that works very well, now I came to know, how little I know about cursors and the methods used on them.

Comment: also you shouldn't use `String.valueOf(cursor.getPosition()+1))` but rather some id (fx ROWID)